# Python: Getting a list from **args to run in a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, args, keyword-argument

I'm trying to run a function that takes a list of player ranks that creates a dictionary (game_on) that has values that are above the average rank of that game should the game be fair (which I have set up in another function). I'm having trouble understanding why when I run Line 15 that I cannot run the list that I accessed in the for loop

```
def is_fair_game(*player_ranks):
    for args in player_ranks:
        if len(player_ranks) == 0:
            return False
        if len(player_ranks) % 2 == 0:
            highest = max(player_ranks)
            lowest = min(player_ranks)
            return highest-lowest <= 5
        else:
            return False

def matchmaking(**games):
    game_on = {}
    for g, args in games.items():
        if is_fair_game(args[0:len(args)]) == False:
            game_on[g] = 'not a fair game'
        if is_fair_game(args) == True:
            for i in args:
                if i >= mean(args):
                    game_on[g].append[i]
        if len(game_on[g]) == 0:
            game_on[g] = 'not a fair game'
    return game_on

matchmaking(game_1=[50, 49, 51, 52], game_2=[71, 73, 71, 71], game_3=[18, 23, 22, 18])
```

[The list of Game One doesn't run through my is_fair_game function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trsHo.png)

Comment: your `is_fair_game` function always hits a `return` statement in the loop, so the function only ever processes the first item in the loop before it exits. It's really not clear what you intend this function to do - if you explain that, we might be able to help you rewrite it so that it works as you intend.

Comment: Would you explain what you expect to be the output of these functions? As of now you have many syntax errors, and the desired result isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

1. `args[0:len(args)]` is always the same thing as `args` (in your instance - since you aren't modifying `args`), and much less readable - change that to just `args`.
2. Your `for` loop in `is_fair_game` is useless, as `args` is never used.
3. To unpack a list into many positional arguments, e.g. `is_fair_game([1, 2, 3])` becomes `is_fair_game(1, 2, 3)`, use the `*` symbol. So your code becomes: `is_fair_game(*args)`. **However I do not recommend writing `is_fair_game` to take a variable number of arguments. The benefit of using a `list` as an argument is that it can be any length, so why bother unpacking it in the first place? Especially since in your code a list would be sufficient.
4. Evaluate booleans directly, don't compare them to `False` or `True`. So `if is_fair_game(*args) == False:` becomes `if not is_fair_game(*args):`

Comment: For lists, `args[0:len(args)]` makes a copy of the list. You could do so more efficiently with `args.copy()`, or more compactly with `args[:]`. I'd also suggest perhaps changing `is_fair_game` to not take `*args`, just `args` without the star. Now the caller doesn't need to unpack anything. And there's no need to copy the list, since the function doesn't mutate it at all.

Comment: OP's function doesn't modify `args` inside `is_fair_game`, but I agree unpacking does seem unnecessary in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few changes in your code, and is now running by the rules you wanted to implement (if I interpreted them correctly).

I removed the loop in the `is_fair_game` function, given it was both not looping (it always stopped in the first element) and it was not necessary as well. I removed the * in `is_fair_game(*player_ranks)` as suggested by Blckknght.

Down the road, you compute an average, so I imported numpy to compute it.

```
import numpy as np

def is_fair_game(player_ranks):

    if len(player_ranks) == 0:
        return False
    if len(player_ranks) % 2 == 0:
        highest = max(player_ranks)
        lowest = min(player_ranks)
        return highest-lowest <= 5
    else:
        return False

def matchmaking(**games):
    game_on = {}
    #insert the keys in the dictionary, and an empty list
    for g in games:
        game_on[g] = []
    for g, args in games.items():
        if is_fair_game(args[:]) == False:
            game_on[g] = 'not a fair game'
        if is_fair_game(args):
            for i in args:
                if i >= np.mean(args):
                    game_on[g].append(i)
        if len(game_on[g]) == 0:
            game_on[g] = 'not a fair game'
    return game_on

matchmaking(game_1=[50, 49, 51, 52], game_2=[71, 73, 71, 71], game_3=[18, 23, 22, 18])
```

There were some other mistakes that I corrected, but you can check on the code itself. Hopefully this works out.